# What do you call a rock climbing wall with spinning wall sections?

Tags: equipment

At a local sports complex there's a rock climbing wall where all the "holds" are spinning wheels, so you have to really watch your balance.

What is the standard name for this type of climbing wall? I'm trying to google it to find other ones but I can't seem to find the right words to get google to see what I'm looking for.

I have tried "spinning climbing hold wall", but get repair and how-to articles about how to keep normal rock climbing holds from spinning.

For context: this is either a rock climbing or indoor ninja related activity

Comment: The title of this question sounds like it should be a joke told in the rock climbing community.

Comment: I would question its utility as well; holds that move with you would completely change the body mechanics of hold transitions in a way that wouldn’t transfer to real climbing well.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no standard name.  Someone came up with the idea, and others imitated it (or came up with it independently), but I've never heard a true standard.  The closest I've heard to a standard is *"spinny wall thing"*.  Example of usage: *"I just twisted my ankle after falling off that stupid spinny wall thing again".*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like something manufacturer-specific, and as far as I'm aware there isn't any common name for what you're describing.

American climbing wall manufacturer Climbing Solutions has a couple of products that could be what you're describing:

[Revolving Wheels](https://www.climbingsolutions.com/walls/revolving-wheels/)

[Spinning Discs](https://www.climbingsolutions.com/walls/spinning-discs/)

Comment: Yeah, it's not a standard thing I've seen in over 10 years of climbing (mainly UK based, admittedly). It's more the kind of thing you'd get in "activity" based climbing places like Clip and Climb.

Comment: I feel this is something that is getting popular with the rise of "ninja warrior" style climbing walls and features. Glad you could find some references, I couldn't find anything myself.